# Is There a Way to Display a Specific User's Instagram Feed?

Tags: ios, ios7, instagram, tabbed

I'm creating a tabbed iOS application. I need one of the tabbed pages to only show the IG feed of a specific user (not the user who logs in). How do I go about doing so?

`Edited:` Ok, now I've registered my app via the IG Developer page, and I've gotten my client id. Now I need the user's profile to load up in my web view.

Here is my code in my **InstaViewController.m** file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *activityView=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];

    activityView.center=self.view.center;

    [activityView startAnimating];

    [self.view addSubview:activityView];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NSURL *instagramURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"instagram://user?username=MAMA_MIA"];

    if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:instagramURL]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:instagramURL];

}

  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the following URI from the Instagram API, you can get any users feed if you know their user ID.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{USER_ID}/media/recent/?client_id={CLIENT_ID}
```

Comment: Thanks, do I absolutely have to register to get a client id to do this?

Comment: I believe so. If you don't add the client id on to the end of the URI you get an error returned. May be worth looking into the IG API further though.

Comment: Ok, I've got my client id. Now my webview is just showing a blank page. I'll show you my code . . .

Comment: Ah, you were not clear in how you wanted to achieve this functionality. The URI I gave was assuming that you would be making a web service request, and displaying the results in a UICollectionView.

Comment: In that case, surely you just need: "instagram.com/{USERNAME}"

Comment: Yes, this was my first instinct, but the user's profile is private and wants it to remain that way (I guess to gain followers), and so it's making it a little more complex.

Comment: You didn't mention that either.  In that case, I don't know how you would handle private users - sorry.

Comment: Yeah, I think my best bet would be to convince my client to make the profile public for the sake of the app.

Comment: If I wanted to go ahead and make the web service request, where would I do so in my implementation file? Would I create another class for it? . . .

Comment: I mostly use AFNetworking for HTTP requests, and have a dedicated class which has methods that allow me to make the various CRUD requests. If this is the only request you will be making, then you could get away with doing it in the implementation file using something like NSURLRequest: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html